# Why do i get ''not defined because of singularities''?

Tags: r, regression, survival-analysis

So I am running a survival analysis on my dataset of google playstor downloads.
My analysis using survreg only provides me with nas for coefficients though.

> "(5 not defined because of singularities)"

If I use a normal lm regression this problem does not occur. This would not work however since all observations of the dependent variable are right censored for a different number (the numeric value is also the limit).

My original dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/lava18/google-play-store-apps

So here I will show you my entire code. It might be a bit long so scroll to the end for the survival analysis, but I wanted to give you the ability to fully comprehend.

```
library(readxl)
Dataset <- read_excel("Thesis/googleplaystore.xlsx")
View(Dataset)
#selecteer 500 apps
set.seed(1998)
dataset <- Dataset[sample(nrow(Dataset), 500), ]
View(dataset)
#Lastupdated --> days_since
end <- matrix( c("2018-08-31"), nrow=500, ncol=1, byrow=FALSE)
end <- format(as.Date(end), "%Y/%m/%d")
View(end)
dataset$`Last Updated` <- as.Date(dataset$`Last Updated`,
                       format = "%B %d, %Y")
dataset$`Last Updated` <- format(as.Date(dataset$`Last Updated`), "%Y/%m/%d")
View(dataset)
install.packages('lubridate')
library(lubridate)
elapsed.time <- dataset$`Last Updated` %--% end
View(elapsed.time)
dataset$days_since <- as.duration(elapsed.time) / ddays(1)
View(dataset)
# + verwijdern uit aantal installs
dataset$Install <- gsub("\\+","", dataset$Installs)
View(dataset)
dataset$Install <- gsub(",","", dataset$Install)
# installs en price numeric maken
typeof(dataset$Install)
dataset$Install <- as.numeric(dataset$Install)
View(dataset)
typeof(dataset$Rating)
dataset$Rating <- as.numeric(dataset$Rating)
typeof(dataset$Reviews)
typeof(dataset$Price)
dataset$Price <- gsub("\\$","", dataset$Price)
dataset$Price <- as.numeric(dataset$Price)
typeof(dataset$days_since)

#Tobit Survival analyses
library(help=survival)
library(survival)
dataset$ins_cen <- matrix( c("0"), nrow=500, ncol=1, byrow=FALSE)
typeof(dataset$ins_cen)
dataset$ins_cen <- as.numeric(dataset$ins_cen)
install.packages('tidyverse')
library(tidyverse)
dataset_2 <- dataset %>% filter(!is.na(dataset$Rating))
View(dataset_2)
dataset_2$dum_cen <- ifelse(dataset_2$ins_cen == 0, 0, 1)
dataset_2$dum_fac <- as.factor(dataset_2$dum_cen)
survreg(Surv(Install, ins_cen, type= 'right') ~  Rating + Price + Reviews + days_since,
        dist="gaussian", data = dataset_2)
cor(dataset)
#CRCH
install.packages('crch')
library(crch)
View(dataset)
CRCH <- crch(Install ~ Rating + Price + Size + Reviews +days_since + `Current Ver` + Category, data = dataset, dist = 'gaussian', right = dataset_2$Install)
```

I tried turning the event into an dummy variable and a factor but both options do not work. The dummy variable changes nothing, while the factor variable gives an error.

> Error in survreg(Surv(Install, dum_fac, type = "right") ~ Rating +
>   Price +  :    multi-state survival is not supported

Thanks for any help.
Sorry if I am asking stupid questions but I am still learning and can't figure my problem out.

p.s. I also tried to solve my problem using `crch()` but this lead to a different error, where I can't seem to wrap my head around either.

> Error in optim(par = start, fn = loglikfun, gr = gradfun, method =
>   method,  :    non-finite value supplied by optim

Edit: I noticed I left character variables in the crch code.
When this is removed from the formula I get a different error.

> Error in solve.default(hessfun(par)) :  system is computationally
>   singular: reciprocal condition number = 7.31468e-142

CRCH code:

```
#CRCH
install.packages('crch')
library(crch)
View(dataset)
CRCH <- crch(Install ~ Rating + Price + Reviews +days_since, data = dataset, dist = 'gaussian', left = -Inf, right = dataset_2$Install)
x = Price + Size + Reviews +days_since + `Current Ver` + Category
```

Comment: I don't understand what an event is. Survival analysis has a time variable and an event variable. You should describe how you are defining each of them. All you are offering are error messages for code that isn't working.

Comment: If you don't respond to requests for clarification, you are unlikely to get further effort.

Comment: Sorry the problem was solved and I forgot to mention that on this site. The event was basically the scraping of the dataset. I problably shouldn't even be using a survival analyses in the first place since it is not really a survival situation where some make it to a certain point and some don't. The only reason I wanted to use survival analyses was the ability to use multiple limits.